# How to Count Average from table databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

i want to Count average from my databases.

for example when i run a sql query like this

```
SELECT user.nama_u AS Nama_Siswa,
       nilai.nilai_n AS Nilai_Pelajaran
       FROM nilai,
            user
       WHERE nilai.id_sw = user.id_u
             AND user.pangkat_u = 'Siswa'
             AND nilai.kelas_n = 'I'
       ORDER BY user.nama_u DESC
```

i have table like this

```
Nama_Siswa               Nilai_Pelajaran
===============          ===============     
Teuku Zul Hidayat        75
Teuku Zul Hidayat        60 
Ferry Mulia Ramadhani    100
Ferry Mulia Ramadhani    80
Apri Sara Diwa           80
Apri Sara Diwa           70
```

what i have modify from sql query from above if i want to show average of Nilai_Pelajaran?

so the table must be like this

```
Nama_Siswa               Average
===============          ===============     
Teuku Zul Hidayat        67.5
Ferry Mulia Ramadhani    90
Apri Sara Diwa           75
```

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your query to use aggregate functions (in this case [`AVG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)) and `GROUP BY` `nama_u`:

```
SELECT user.nama_u AS Nama_Siswa, AVG(nilai.nilai_n) AS Nilai_Pelajaran 
FROM nilai
JOIN user 
WHERE nilai.id_sw = user.id_u AND user.pangkat_u = 'Siswa' AND nilai.kelas_n = 'I' 
GROUP BY user.nama_u
ORDER BY user.nama_u DESC
```

Comment: Note that we normally use the JOIN...ON construction

Comment: @Strawberry indeed. However I didn't want to change any more of OPs query than was absolutely necessary (i.e. changing `,` to `JOIN` :-).